# Emachines E525 laptop not displaying

Tags: motherboard

Hello everyone i have a laptop Emachines E525 switch on showing the blue light but  its not displaying and i tried to put on external monitor but still the same the problem is when i switch the laptop on the fan runs few minutes and stop but the light still showing blue if i remove the ram it doesn't beep please help me. i have tried to change the processor but its still the same and i open the laptop and i have seen water drops and i tried to clean motherboard with the spirit and blow it with hot station.

Comment: So it's water damaged and you've reflowed it and it still doesn't work? Time for a new machine ...

Comment: The lack of grammar made this very difficult to read. Mind cleaning that up a bit?

Answer (score 0):

You have seen water drops, so there's a clear indication of water damage. Unfortunately for everyone involved, water can do **a lot** of damage in places you won't even notice.

Because of this, there are simply too many possibilities for what could be wrong. With the possibility of water shorting out various components, there is also a real possibility that you will damage additional components if you try to swap them in.

If you are feeling particularly confident:

- Ensure everything is completely dry
- Ensure there is no visible damage to any of the components
- Swap major components (motherboard, hard-drive, CPU, memory, etc...) until issue is resolved

Without any real way to diagnose the issue (and the information you have given us is in no way enough for us to diagnose it for you), you are basically shooting in the dark at this point.

Due to the wide range of potential issues, and the aforementioned water damage, I would consider this a **total loss**.

Consider that you could replace it with a used, equivalent system from Ebay for < $100. At this point, it is simply not economical to spend more time than you already have to salvage this old, outdated system. That's not even including the potential cost of replacement parts.